# How does Bootstrap Pull and push work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to fix a page which wasn't bootstrapped like the illustration. But my `col-2`, `col-3`, `col-4` don't align with the col 1 and 2. I cannot really understand how pull and push work. I have worked on my mobile layout and it seem fine, but as it goes to desktop, it messing the layout. 
[image: Illustration of layout to understand]

My layout becomes this, when I make it go desktop. Misaligned headings and columns under it. [image: What i get]

Comment: Can you provide a working code sample please?

Comment: @JohannKratzik the code is really bad. Also much of java stuff so it is like stripping all out for nothing. I rather code something new if i can understand how pull and pull work in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include yellow div-s into `row` so they won't jump over next line.

```css
.left-box {
    height: 290px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #e66;
    margin: 3px;
}

.right-box {
    height: 70px;
    background: #ee6;
    margin: 3px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .left-box, .right-box {
       height: 200px;
    }    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-5">
            <div class="left-box"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-7">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"><div class="right-box"></div></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><div class="right-box"></div></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><div class="right-box"></div></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><div class="right-box"></div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: according to bootstrap rules, the statement `class="col-md-2 col-sm-5"` is the same that `class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-5 col-xs-12"`.

Comment: Thanks, but i cannot figure out why do we need a .row twice, shouldn't it be one time? from my understanding a row in like horizontal block.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need push-pull classes I think. You could use a markup like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="left-box"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="right-box"></div>
            <div class="right-box"></div>
            <div class="right-box">etc...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yVKgwG

Comment: That is a screen for desktop, i need that layout in mobile and col in desktop.

Comment: You only talk about "mobile" and "desktop" but not if you used -md- or -sm- classes or whatever. And you say that it's impossible for you to post a code snippet.