# Is it possible to nest col-xs-1 to smaller parts with responsive method - bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, nested

I really like bootstrap grids, however, what I miss is a method to nest even smaller parts. for an example col-xs-1, col-md-1 etc. It would be really cool if this smallest columns could be organised as full screen grid. Is there any way to do this perhaps?

Comment: sure. you can nest grids inside cells as much as you wish. look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/40980536/4206079 . There is one condition - nested grids will be styled for actual viewport width, not for cell dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want this? Bootstrap is made to easily adapt sizes based on their viewport. So, if you would like to have a specific div to be 50% width on medium and 100% width on extra small, just add the right classes.

```
<html>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                //do something
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

This way, your div will be md-6 on medium viewport and full screen and extra small viewport. Hope this answers your question.

Edit:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-4">
               // content here
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-4">
               // content here
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-4">
               // content here
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: sure i understand this. But let's assume you would like to split col-xs-1 on 12 parts with responsive bootstrap method... Is there any way you could do that?

Comment: I've edited my post. I think this answers your question ;)